# how to read from a zipfile in a folder which was selected by the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE Intent?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

how to read from a zipfile in a folder which was selected by the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE Intent ?

My app let the user choose a folder through the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE Intent.
In that folder i will have a Zipfile with a specific name.
Goal is to read that Zipfile with java.util.zip.ZipFile.

How do I instantiate a ZipFile with this specific Zipfilename from the provided URI (Folderinfo) in onActivityResult ?

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Uri treeUri = data.getData();
    String sPath=treeUri.getPath();

    java.util.zip.ZipFile myzip=new java.util.zip.ZipFile("mypath"); <-- Constructor expects File or Path as String. Howto handle this with the Uri ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I instantiate a ZipFile with this specific Zipfilename from the provided URI (Folderinfo) in onActivityResult ?

You can't, as there is no file, and `ZipFile` needs a file. You can only get an `InputStream`, using `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver`, and that only if you get a `Uri` to that specific file that you are looking for.

Your options appear to be:

- Use `ZipInputStream`, which can wrap an `InputStream`
- Find some third-party library that accepts an `InputStream` as input and gives you a better API
- Copy the ZIP flie to your app's portion of internal storage and read its contents using `ZipFile`

Comment: As I wrote. I will have a zipfile already in that folder, which the user selects. So is there really noch chance to instantiate a ZipFile on this already existing File based on the Folder-URI ?

Comment: @user1344545: As *I* wrote, **there is no file**. `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` does not return a "Folder-URI". It returns a `Uri` to whatever the `DocumentProvider` wants it to be. There is no requirement that it map to some directory on the device itself. A `Uri` that a `DocumentProvider` returns for a particular document does not have to map to some file on the device itself. For example, a  `DocumentProvider` can be backed by "the cloud" rather than by local files, or the files may be on removable media that the provider can access but that you cannot.

Comment: If I manually move a zipfile "myzip.zip" to a folder /sdcard/myfolder/ with an fileexplorer (Thats what I mean with there is already a file). Then I start the app and choose the folder /sdcard/myfolder with the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE Intent and I see the file "myzip.zip" . Then I expect that the file is there and I can list it out with the API hopefully. So I hoped to read this file also. But thanks I will try with ZipInputStream

Comment: @user1344545 - no, your expectation is wrong.  There is not necessarily any actual "file", and even if there is, depending on location it may only be accessible to some Android internal daemon, and not directly to your app.  The ZipInputStream method is how you are *supposed* to do this, as it leverages the fact that while many of these abstractions will not expose an actual File to you, *they will give you an InputStream* proxied through whatever the implementation actually is behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I already Implemented the ZipInputStream Solution suggested from CommonsWare. I have also accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on this problem and ended up going with a strategy @CommonsWare mentioned as the third option, which is copying a file to non-sdcard place and load as a ZipFile. It works well so I share my snippet for everybody.

```
 public static ZipFile loadCachedZipFromUri(Context context, Uri uri, String filename){
    File file = new File(context.getCacheDir(), filename);
    String fileName = context.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() + '/' + filename;
    ZipFile zip = null;

    if (file.exists()){
        Log.d(TAG, "file exists");
        try {
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) { // N for Nougat
                zip = new ZipFile(fileName, Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));

            }else{
                zip = new ZipFile(fileName);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return zip;
    }

    DocumentFile dest = DocumentFile.fromFile(file);

    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;

    Log.d(TAG, "Copy started");
    try {
        in = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        out = context.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(dest.getUri());
        byte[] buf = new byte[2048];
        int len = 0;
        while((len = in.read(buf)) >= 0){
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        try {
            in.close();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "Load copied file");
    try {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) { // N for Nougat
            zip = new ZipFile(fileName, Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));

        }else{
            zip = new ZipFile(fileName);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return zip;
}
```